# Customize MS Dynamics CRM entity in Visual Studio 2008 with JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm

I have installed the MS Dynamics CRM on my windows server 2003. I want to add the javascript to the one of entity that has drop down control, let's say Opportunity entity. But I don't know how to open the CRM in Visual Studio so that i can make changes. I have installed CRM explorer as well as Install the CRM Solution Framework (under folder\CRMSolutionFrameworkTemplate\Setup.cmd)
Using command prompt to install: Setup.cmd {InstallDir} {ProjectName} {Project Long Name} {Organization Name}

How to make the changes, how to get the CRM in VS for edit
While opening the solution from "C:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\SourceCode\MyCrmSolution"
It gives error as :"Mcrosoft.sourceanalysis.target not found error so it can not open the solution". please guide I am new in this stuff....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done thru customization only. You just have to open the form by going to the Settings > Customization > Customize Entity > Opportunity and customize it from there.

Visual Studio is only used to do advanced customization, such as Plugins, Workflow Activities or ASPX pages, every thing else can be done using customization.

Comment: oh,thanks. But what i have to do for add my own events and script to the page?

Comment: Open the main form, and click on the onChange event you can add script in there.